# SwiftUI navigationBarHidden doesn't work and throws error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am pushing next view with navigation link

```
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView()
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true),
                       isActive: $isDetailsActive) {
            EmptyView()
        }
```

I tried the same inside details view too. All I am getting is empty Navigation Bar on Details View and error in terminal:

> "changing items while animating can result in a corrupted navigation
>   bar"

Comment: Would you show complete code where is this activated from?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I have the same problem with an unpredictable nav bar...

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you should not push or pop new views on the navigation controller until it’s finished with the last push or pop.

Answer (score 1):

I hide  my navigation bar using `.onAppear` and `.onDisappear`, you can place those modifiers in your parent view or in DetailsView(), look:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavBarHidden)
    .onAppear {
        self.isNavBarHidden = true
    }.onDisappear {
        self.isNavBarHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `onDisappear()` is not called in the main view when the secondary view is pushed onto the nav stack and the main view is no longer visible. It is only called when the main view is completely gone. So I'm not sure how this addresses the issue…

Comment: It works perfectly for me, are you doing something different? @Anton

Comment: Sorry, @zgluis — I'm not sure exactly what you're saying works because I'm afraid I don't understand how you're proposing that the code you give be integrated with the OP's code. I'm just commenting on your statement that `.onAppear` and `.onDisappear` can be placed in the parent view. In fact neither of those modifiers are invoked in the parent view when the child view is pushed onto the navigation stack, and neither is invoked when the child view is popped and the parent view become visible again. You can verify that by placing `print()` functions inside them—they never print.

Comment: No problem, I just want to help @Anton. I created a gist with a full working example: https://gist.github.com/zgluis/5d7fc8f747a526dfb2aa9133f2785f59, I also noticed that isNavBarHidden must be initialized on false

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.When I run your code in Xcode 11.5 the `.onAppear` and `.onDisappear` closures never fire. I'm wondering what you intend them for. It also displays the current iOS bug in which hiding the nav bar in the parent view erroneously hides it in the child view in a jerky motion at the end of the transition.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 NavigationView {

    some code {..}

   .navigationBarTitle("")
   
   .navigationBarHidden(true)

}
```

It seems that the `navigationBarTitle` seems to be set at `("")`, for the `.navigationBarHidden(true)` to work within a `NavigationView` (Xcode Version 13)